# Most important tips to make JavaScript pretty

Tags: javascript, coding-style, coffeescript

CoffeeScript seems to be gaining traction from even non-python devs because of how it looks nice. I'm curious if anyone has a good tip(s) to make JavaScript look pretty by hand. I personally enjoy the JavaScript look, but just as an example part answer/part of an answer:

```
var a = 'b';
var foo = 'bar';
var hello = function(){ alert('world'); }
var lorem = 'ipsum';
```

Can (should) be written like:

```
var a = 'b'
,   foo = 'bar'
,   hello = function(){ alert('world'); }
,   lorem = 'ipsum'
```

This isn't nessacarily a disussion, but a question of, **"if you had a complete newbie at JavaScript as an intern, what are the most important methods of keeping your JavaScript clean and legible without any pseudo languages or parsers?"**

Comment: This is really subjective.  I prefer the first version.

Comment: [jshint is not as opinionated as jslint](http://jshint.com/)

Comment: @Raynos: That looks interesting, I use lint because it's installed as a plugin in my text editor.

Comment: I prefer JSHint by far... Brendan Eich says "suck it" to JSLint

Comment: Why is this closed? The two answers I got are perfect and help others and i can pick a right answer. I honestly don't get why style guides and best practices are bad. Maybe i should just rename it to "Best style practices for JS" and it wont be closed: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=best+practices+javascript

Comment: You might want to try posting at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. That seems to be where subjective Stack Overflow questions are going these days.

Comment: @OscarGodson: I attempted to migrate this to Programmers but no one else agreed. It's definitely **not** a proper SO question, unless there is a definitive source that can tell us for a fact what "looks pretty".

Answer (score 4):

What I always recommend to anyone who is interested in this kind of thing is: **STICK TO WHAT YOUR TEAM DOES**. If they use `camelCase` for methods, you use it. If they use `snake_case` for variables, you do it. If your team prefers spaces over tabs; use them.

Never go into a stablished team with standardized style changing things because it looks better unless it's causing heavy problems.

If you're not working on a team and you're interested on using a coding style; then **use the style of the libraries you use the most**.

- If you use `jQuery` stick to [jQuery Coding Style Guidelines](http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines)
- If you use `Closure` Library use [JavaScript Google Coding Style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml)
- If you use `MooTools` Library use [MooTools Coding Style Guideline](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/wiki/syntax-and-coding-style-conventions)

Comment: Never heard that called `snake_case` before, I kind of like it. Did you mean `If your team prefers spaces over tabs; fire them`? Why was this closed as subjective again? :)

Comment: @WesleyMurch You use tabs? I'm never hiring you

Comment: Hah! Indeed, some people like to use spaces because they're using Python or Ruby which usually means 2 spaces for the indentation. I once tried to change a whole team who used spaces over tabs on javascript... it was not a good idea. So I wrote a parser that would do the magic for me on deployment.. Regarding why it closed.. Idk, sadly my answer is not worth anything now.

Comment: I answered the question objectively... so meh.

Comment: My statement is proof that this is an argumentative topic. I was just kidding :D Your answer is still quite valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Follow a style guideline.

I personally agree with most of [the google style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml).

Use a ES5 or a library that introduces functional style sugar like [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/).

Writing solid consistent functional code in JavaScript should make your code look legible, terse and readable.